# "module parse failed" error in gatsby-browser-entry.js

Tags: gatsby

I'm new to gatsby and react. We're building a site for a small project using gatsby and decoupled drupal. I'm getting the following error, since I connected the frontend and backend, when I run 'gatsby develop'.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/Gatsby/cache-dir/gatsby-browser-entry.js 22:4
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (22:4)

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|   return (
>     <React.Fragment>
|       {finalData && render(finalData)}
|       {!finalData && <div>Loading (StaticQuery)</div>}
 @ ./src/pages/index.js 24:0-33 157:19-26
 @ ./.cache/sync-requires.js
 @ ./.cache/app.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/event-source-polyfill/src/eventsource.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?path=/__webpack_hmr&reload=true&overlay=false
```

Comment: That's odd -- it looks like it doesn't recognize jsx. Do you have a custom webpack / babel config in `gatsby-node.js`?

Comment: did you solved this issue?

Comment: I found out this happens when you're trying to use a gatsby hook outside of React context, for example Link from gatsby

Answer (score 0):

Was having this issue and found this workaround:

```ts
// import { Link } from "gatsby" // error 
import Link from "gatsby-link" // not error
```

It works for me! :)

Font: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10668#issuecomment-546596273